# Android Action Bar Button between spacing

Tags: android

I am using a BaseTheme which is used all across the app. I want to
reduce the spacing between Action bar menu buttons ( 3 icons at the
left of overflow button ). I tried by over riding ActionButtonStyle,
but it didnt work out. Still, action button spacing is more. If any
one faced this issue & resolved, Please tell me the solution.

```
<style name="BaseTheme"
parent="@style/Theme.Base.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"> <item
name="android:editTextStyle">@style/EditText</item> <item
name="android:checkboxStyle">@style/CheckBox</item> <item
name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/MyActionButtonStyle</item>
<item
name="actionButtonStyle">@style/MyActionButtonCompatStyle</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item> </style>
```

And, I have defined the following for overriding ActionButtonStyle,

```
    <style name="MyActionButtonStyle"
    parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton"> <item
    name="android:minWidth">0dip</item> <item
    name="android:paddingLeft">0dip</item> <item
    name="android:paddingRight">0dip</item> <item
    name="android:paddingStart">12dip</item> <item
    name="android:paddingEnd">12dip</item> </style>

<style name="MyActionButtonCompatStyle"
parent="Widget.AppCompat.Base.ActionButton"> <item
name="android:paddingLeft">0dip</item> <item
name="android:paddingRight">0dip</item> <item
name="android:minWidth">0dip</item> </style>
```